# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Tag found

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I was trying to do web scraping and was using the following code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.indianexpress.com/news/indian-actions-discriminating-against-us-exp/1131015/"
br =  mechanize.Browser()
htmltext = br.open(url).read()
articletext = ""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for tag in soup.findAll('p'):
    articletext += tag.contents[0]
print articletext
```

But I was getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/crawler/express.py", line 15, in <module>
    articletext += tag.contents[0]
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Tag found
```

Can someone helo me to sort this error out, I am new to Python programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For at least one `<p>` tag found, `tag.contents[0]` is a `Tag` object, not text. For the specific URL you found, it's a `<hr>` tag:

```
>>> tag
<p><hr> </hr></p>
```

Why not use `tag.text` instead of `tag.contents[0]`?

```
for tag in soup.findAll('p'):
    articletext += tag.text
```